# Migrating Silverstripe CMS system from one server to another

Tags: php, content-management-system, migrate, silverstripe

Im relatively new to silverstripe cms and Im trying to move a site to a new host.
I followed all the instructions I could find on their official forums but to no avail.

Here is what I mean.
Here you can see what the site should look like

http://www.efekto.co.za

But this is what it looks like after I have moved it (copied everything to my public_html folder on the new site, set up the db username and passwords etc)

Please help cause I'm utterly and truly stuck at the moment.

[image]

Since someone else initialy moved the site so I decided to delete everything and move everything myself. Its hard to explain otherwise what I have tried or not tried.

First I tried to install just a base silverstripe. Got that right pretty much but only after I specified the database ip as 127.0.0.1 and not the external ip. So I deleted the base install again, copied over all the site files again and this time modified the db params to use 127.0.0.1 Some of the pages now actually reflect valid content but it seems that everything is not this light blue kind of color (seems to be a default of SS? ) It is as if it's missing some kind of master page or something as I can see content, but no module thingies like menus, blog section etc.

I also have to mention that to test this I change my hosts file so that www.efecto.co.za resolves to the sites new ip address with our new host. So from my machine it resolves to new ip but from the servers perspective when it fetches things like css its obviously going to fecth it from where www.efekto.co.za is currently hosted. Hope that makes sense?

So 1 step in the right direction at least. We have content and no more errors. Now whats up with this blue color scheme??

Comment: cant answer definitely so a comment will do, did you use phpmyadmin to export the database then on the new host import the db? is there any config files within the script or the database that need appending to your new hosts path/urls ect, also sometimes .htaccess files contain a baseurl. The url in the image is the same as the working version so not sure what you have done so far.

Comment: If you're running the database on the same server, it's highly advisable to limit connections to 127.0.0.1 for security reasons so this shouldn't be a real surprise

Answer (score 1):

http://www.efekto.co.za seems to be fine now.

My guess: You've had a `silverstripe-cache` folder on your old server, which you've copied. It contains (as you might suspect) cached files with absolute paths. If your path structure is not exactly the same on both servers, you will run into problems. So always remove everything from the cache folder when moving sites around.

If that isn't the problem, take a look at the Apache log file (probably `/var/log/apache2/error.log`, but this can vary). As it's a server error, it should tell you what the problem is...

Comment: currently www.efekto.co.za is the old site. that one runs perfectly its on the new site that things go screwy. Ill check out some of your suggestions in the meantime, thanks.

Comment: Where can I find this cache folder you mention?

Comment: Right besides ``mysite``, ``sapphire``,... - but it's optional (even though common), you might not have it at all

Comment: Had a look. Found the sapphire directory but inside it I see no cache folder of any kind. Please have a look at my updated question since I've had some (a little) progress. Oh and holy crap, your helping me at 2 in the morning?!!

Comment: Not inside, directly in the base folder where ``mysite``, ``sapphire``,... are. If it's not there, it's something else. If you don't have access to the log files, maybe you can enable the display of errors in PHP or ask the provider for the log entries? Without them it's more or less guessing... PS: Yep, already 2 again, time for bed now ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Check the error log in cpanel or whatever, perhaps a PHP or APACHE directive is different on this server. You'll find out from the logs what the problem is.
I got this once and the problem was that /dev/build wouldn't run because the php memory upper limit was set higher in SS than it was on the server.
Also go into _config and set the environment directive to 'debug', this will display as much output as SS can give you on the page.